# How do I say ''Don't do things halfway.'' in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I need to know how to say''Don't do things halfway.'' in Latin?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Another option, perhaps:

> *dimidium facti parum est.*
> Half of a deed is inadequate/too little/not enough.

This is a 'mash-up' of two passages:

- Horace, *Epistulae* 1.2.40:

  > *dimidium facti, qui coepit, habet.*
  > He who has begun has half of the deed.
- Lucan, *Bellum civile* 5.274:

  > *quid satis est, si Roma parum est?*
  > What's enough if Rome is not enough?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it is possible to translate literally, but lets examine other options:

we can use *conata* or *conatus*(4th dec.) or *coeptum* to denote things started/hoped/attempted, as in Caesar *Perfacile factu esse illis probat **conata perficere*** ; or this:

> Neque vero ille ob eam causam **conatu desistebat**, sed labore et perseverantia nautarum etiam vim tempestatis superari posse sperabat.

So we can can say: **noli desistere conatu**

Another verse from Ovid: *nec **coeptum dimittit iter*** (Ov.Met.2.598).

Or to render on the positive, we can use the formula of non other than Venus(?):

> mota Cytheriaca leviter mea tempora myrto
> contigit et “**coeptum perfice**” dixit “**opus**.” (Ov.Fast.4.16).

Most simply I search for *quod coepitsi* but only one line from Seneca showed (*Preme ergo quod coepisti* [SenPhil.Ep.20.6.4])